# Как считать из span с помощью textContext

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Подскажите, почему при попытке считать `textContent` из `span`, выдает ошибку:

> Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

Хотя на **stackoverflow** и других онлайн редакторах ошибки нет.
Нужно считать то что внутри тега `<span>`, как это можно сделать?
Вот пример:

```js
var a = document.getElementById('s').textContent;
console.log(a);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="s">5</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Браузер начинает выполнять такой скрипт, как только его загрузит.

На момент выполнения скрипта элемент на странице еще не существует.

Вариантов решения несколько:

—

Поместите скрипт после создания тега `<span>`:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<span id="s">5</span>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

—-

Дождитесь загрузки страницы:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    var a = document.getElementById('s').textContent;
    console.log(a);

});
```

—-

Использовать `<script async>` или `<script defer>` , однако такие скрипты выполняются сразу после загрузки и я так понимаю что в общем случае не факт что страница к этому моменту прогрузится полностью, однако я не встречал такого поведения...

Comment: Тут вспомнил про атрибут defer,
попробовал, вроде работает, 
он подойдет?

Comment: @Greetven скорее да, чем нет, я дополнил ответ

Comment: Хорошей практикой считается, располагать скрипты перед `</body>`